# Batch file to open multiple Explorer Windows in single instance of explorer.exe

Tags: windows-explorer

Since opening multiple explorer windows via either <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>  or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>  results in those windows being opened in a single instance of the explorer.exe process...  Is it possible to do this via a batch file?

Comment: `start explorer`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the explorer via a batch file create a text document. 
Type "start explorer" (no quotation marks)

Save as, Call it whatever you want .bat and save it as all programs.

Ex call it explorer.bat

Save it to your desktop.

Comment: start explorer [path]
start explorer [path]

Comment: How does the questioner respond to answers?  How is a line break inserted?

Comment: If you're looking to run two commands in your text file.

start explorer

start explorer %programfiles%

This would open 2 file explorers one to your default file explorer one to your program files folder.

Comment: This no longer seems to work in Windows 11. "start explorer [path]" will open a new instance of explorer process for each new window. :(